I was loading the iris dataset, but there is an error where it says duplicate names are not allowed, i even tried changing the name but another error
url= "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris.data"
names = ['sepal-length','sepal-width','petal-length','petal-width','petal-width','class'] 
dataset = pandas.read_csv(url, names = names)


ValueError: Duplicate names are not allowed.

I was expecting this output but instead there was an error

your names list contains the name "petal-width" two times

What @Ze'evBen-Tsvi said. Also, that url is a page of NOT FOUND

Oh! Yeah I didn't notice that, and you are write about the url too, thanks alot.

Officially, the iris dataset belongs to scikit-learn package.
In case you want to do it in the most clever way without using URLs and extracting the information directly from the package, use this code:
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iris = datasets.load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data)
df.columns = ['sepal-length','sepal-width','petal-length','petal-width']
df["class"] = np.arange(0,150,1)
print(df)


You call the scikit-learn package subdivison called dataset which contain the dataset you are looking for, iris.
You use the function load_iris() to load it.
You read the DataFrame with pandas.
You assign the column´s names with df.columns.
In the next line you add the class column that it is not implemented yet, and with np.arange you create a list of numbers from 0 to 149.

Hope it helps!

You can grab the data set here:
import pandas as pd

url= "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7/raw/0e7a9b0a5d22642a06d3d5b9bcbad9890c8ee534/iris.csv"
dataset = pd.read_csv(url)

